# mongo gridfs with python

Tags: python, pymongo, gridfs

I want to serve image from gridfs directly from python script but only what I see is blank screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pymongo import Connection
import gridfs

db = Connection().gridfs_example
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

f= fs.get_last_version('myimage')

print "Content-type: %s \n\n " % f.content_type
print "Content-Length: %d \n\n" % f.length
print f.read()
```

if I write output from f.read() to file I able to see "valid" image
I able to show this image from local FS with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

img = open('image.jpg','rb').read()
print "Content-type: image/jpeg"
print "Content-Length: %d\n" % len(img)
print img
```

what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
```

is the offending line.  The GridFS constructor takes an instance of Database, not a connection object.  So you would have to do something like:

```
conn = Connection()
db = conn['mydb']
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see some raw output from your script.

One thing to check is that the response headers are correctly terminated. The print statement adds a newline character to the end of the output, which means you can remove the second '\n' from the content-type header string.